# Custom select directive with dynamic data load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I try to implement custom directive for select tag:

```
App.directive('customeSelect', function() {
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          label: '@',
          //fdata: "&", //case on call: getUrgencyTypes() - this function from controller
          gdata: "=", //case on call: getUrgencyTypes
          bindedModel: "=ngModel",
          eventHandler: '&ngChange'
        },
        template : '<div class="text-wrap" ng-mousedown="getData()">' +
        '<select class="jcf-select" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="bindedModel" data-ng-change="eventHandler()" ng-options="a[\'val\'] as a[label] for a in select_data" >'+
        '</select></div>',

        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $location) {
            $scope.getData = function (first){
              //get data from model
                //if ($scope.select_data == undefined){
                    var kk = $scope.gdata;
                    $scope.select_data = kk(first);
                //}

            };
            $scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded',  function() {
                // $scope.showSelect = false;
                // console.log("view loaded");
                $scope.getData(true);
                // jcf.replace($element.find("select"));
            });

        }
    }
});
```

And some like I try to use this:

```
custome-select  label="text" fdata="getUrgencyTypes()" ng-model="data.Urgency" data-ng-change="on_main_info_changed()" gdata="getUrgencyTypes"
```

But field is empty when page is loaded. If I click at the field a right value is setting at the field. How I can set right value before a select-field will be shown?

If I use "gdata" - I can pass a parameter to function in controller - but data in a select doesn't show at time, if I use "fdata" - data show at time, but I can't pass a parameter to function in controller. 
I need a parameter because I don't want at first time load all option for select.